# shell scripts to pattern(s) search and list file(s) in a directory

Tags: shell-script

I used `ls | agrep "<search pattern #1>;<search pattern #2>;...;<search pattern #n>"` to quickly and/or effectively perform a search/list of some file(s) in a directory with some search pattern(s). As an illustration, I created an empty directory and filled it with some empty files using the `touch` command as shown below:

```
~ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-bird_dog_cat.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-bird_dog.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-bird.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-cat_dog_bird.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-cat_dog.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-cat.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-dog_bird.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-dog_cat_bird.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-dog_cat.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-dog.txt
```

Then, using `ls -l | agrep "cat;bird"`, I have no problem to search/find file(s) whose name(s) contain only ***cat*** and ***bird*** as shown below.

```
~ ls -l | agrep 'cat;bird'
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-bird_dog_cat.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-cat_dog_bird.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-dog_cat_bird.txt
```

AFAICT, this method is pretty fast and effective (I am all ears for a better solution). Since I do this a lot on a daily base, I thought it may be better to write a simple shell script to perform such a task by simply giving the search pattern(s) in CLI. For instance, I wrote a simple shell scripts as shown below and named it `mls` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
bold=$(tput bold)
italic=$(tput sitm)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "${bold}Usage${normal}: $0 <search string 0> [... <search string n>]"
    exit 0
fi
patterns=""
for ((i=1;i<$#;i++))
do
    patterns+="${!i};"
done
patterns+="${!#}"
/usr/bin/ls -lart | agrep '${patterns}${!#}'
```

Then, when I executed the above shell script with a search pattern of `mls cat bird`, it returns nothing as shown below.

```
~ ls -l | agrep 'cat;bird'
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-bird_dog_cat.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-cat_dog_bird.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 0 May  7 14:00 animals-dog_cat_bird.txt
~ mls cat bird
~
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: The biggest problem is that you are parsing `ls`. See more here and what to do instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: Wow ... and you are right. Thank you and now the scripts work.

Answer (score 3):

You could switch to `zsh` here whose globs support OR, AND (well AND-NOT and NOT) and approximation

```
$  set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
$ ls -ld -- (#a1)*dig*~^(#a1)*bard*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 May  8 16:24 animals-bird_dog_cat.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 May  8 16:24 animals-bird_dog.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 May  8 16:24 animals-cat_dog_bird.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 May  8 16:24 animals-dog_bird.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 May  8 16:24 animals-dog_cat_bird.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I don't use zsh ATM; however, this has been added to my shell script arsenal.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the single quote problem, you're adding the last element twice

```bsh
patterns+="${!#}"
/usr/bin/ls -lart | agrep "${patterns}${!#}"
```

Run the program with `bash -x mls cat bird` to see

---

But you don't need a loop: the `"$*"` special parameter joins the positional parameters using the first character of IFS. If we temporarily define a new value for IFS, we can do

```bsh
patterns=$( IFS=';'; echo "$*" )
```

---

If you don't need the "approximate" part of `agrep`, bash can do this by itself using [extended glob patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

```bsh
pattern=$( IFS='|'; echo "$*" )
shopt -s extglob
ls *@($pattern)*
```

Comment: `@(foo|bar)` does OR, not AND. You'd need `!(!(*cat*)|!(*bird*))` for the equivalent of `agrep`'s `cat;bird`.

Comment: @glenn: Thank you for the suggestion and I like it very much. It makes my shell scripts shorter and faster.